# How the pricing is calculated If I query a Bigquery View?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Say I have a BigQuery View
MyView:
    select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7 from mytable;

Now If I Query my view:
    select col1 from MyView;

So In this case , will the pricing will be calculated for all columns or only for col1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> will the pricing will be calculated for all columns or only for col1?

Only for col1!

You can easily check this in UI by looking into estimation of how many bytes will be processed using

```
select col1 from MyView
```

vs

```
select * from MyView
```

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail Berlyant